# How to remove checked attribute from an input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove checked attribute from an input who is checked as default. I'm working with Isotope filters.

I tried

```
this.prop('checked', false);
```

and

```
this.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

nothing works...

the input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="" class="item 35 40" style="visibility:hidden;" checked>
```

the javascript

```
proto.onHideTransitionEnd = function() {

  if ( this.isHidden ) {
    this.css({ display: 'none' });
    this.emitEvent('hide');
  }
};
```

Comment: What makes you think `this.attr('checked', 'checked')` would **remove** the attribute? Try [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) instead

Comment: Can you share value of `this` in `proto.onHideTransitionEnd` function.?

Comment: removeAttr removes checked attribute itself. So if you cannot use **checked** attribute again. .prop('checked', false) is better.

Comment: What is `proto`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
 this.removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: From OP's code, I would assume `this` is already a jQuery object so doesn't need wrapping in `$(...)`. You also have some odd quote characters in your answer

Answer (score 0):

**In,
jQuery 1.6+**

To change the property of checkbox you should use the .prop() function.

```
$('.prettycheckbox input').prop('checked', false);
$('.prettycheckbox input').prop('checked', true);
```

**jQuery 1.5 and below**

The .prop() function doesn't exist, but .attr() does similar:

```
$('.prettycheckbox input').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Note: removeAttr is valid, but addAttr is not.

Answer (score 0):

nothing work guys, this is the complete code:

```
// remove element from DOM
proto.removeElem = function() {
  this.element.parentNode.removeChild( this.element );
  // remove display: none
  this.css({ display: '' });
  this.emitEvent( 'remove', [ this ] ); 


};



proto.remove = function() {
  // just remove element if no transition support or no transition
  if ( !transitionProperty || !parseFloat( this.layout.options.transitionDuration ) ) {
    this.removeElem();
    return;
  }

  // start transition
  this.once( 'transitionEnd', function() {
    this.removeElem();
  });
  this.hide();
};

proto.reveal = function() {
  delete this.isHidden;
  // remove display: none
  this.css({ display: '' }); 

  var options = this.layout.options;

  var onTransitionEnd = {};
  var transitionEndProperty = this.getHideRevealTransitionEndProperty('visibleStyle');
  onTransitionEnd[ transitionEndProperty ] = this.onRevealTransitionEnd;

  this.transition({
    from: options.hiddenStyle,
    to: options.visibleStyle,
    isCleaning: true,
    onTransitionEnd: onTransitionEnd
  });
};

proto.onRevealTransitionEnd = function() {
  // check if still visible
  // during transition, item may have been hidden
  if ( !this.isHidden ) {
    this.emitEvent('reveal');
  }
};

/**
 * get style property use for hide/reveal transition end
 * @param {String} styleProperty - hiddenStyle/visibleStyle
 * @returns {String}
 */
proto.getHideRevealTransitionEndProperty = function( styleProperty ) {
  var optionStyle = this.layout.options[ styleProperty ];
  // use opacity
  if ( optionStyle.opacity ) {
    return 'opacity';
  }
  // get first property
  for ( var prop in optionStyle ) {
    return prop;
  }
};

proto.hide = function() {
  // set flag
  this.isHidden = true;
  // remove display: none
  this.css({ display: '' });  

  var options = this.layout.options;

  var onTransitionEnd = {};
  var transitionEndProperty = this.getHideRevealTransitionEndProperty('hiddenStyle');
  onTransitionEnd[ transitionEndProperty ] = this.onHideTransitionEnd;

  this.transition({
    from: options.visibleStyle,
    to: options.hiddenStyle,
    // keep hidden stuff hidden
    isCleaning: true,
    onTransitionEnd: onTransitionEnd
  });
};

proto.onHideTransitionEnd = function() {
  // check if still hidden
  // during transition, item may have been un-hidden
  if ( this.isHidden ) {
    this.css({ display: 'none' }); 
    this.emitEvent('hide');

  }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

This will sole the issues:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') == true){
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```